# Whitelisting IP addresses for network traffic through Istio gateways

Tags: kubernetes, istio, whitelist

I tried whitelisting IP address/es in my kubernetes cluster's incoming traffic using [this](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/policy-enforcement/denial-and-list/#ip-based-whitelists-or-blacklists) example :

Although this works as expected, wanted to go a step further and try if I can use `istio` gateways or virtual service when I set up Istio rule, instead of Loadbalancer(ingressgateway).

```
apiVersion: config.istio.io/v1alpha2
kind: rule
metadata:
  name: checkip
  namespace: my-namespace
spec:
  match: source.labels["app"] == "my-app"
  actions:
  - handler: whitelistip.listchecker
    instances:
    - sourceip.listentry
---
```

Where `my-app` is of `kind: Gateway` with a certain host and port, and labelled `app=my-app`.

Am using istio version 1.1.1
Also my cluster has all the istio-system running with envoy sidecars on almost all service pods.

Comment: So what is your question? I do not see any issues with using Istio Ingress Gateway with Istio policies.

Comment: The issue is when I use label matcher to point to the gateway instead of load balancer, it doesnt work. so source.label has to be pointing to the ingress lb itself for it to work. can I not configure this on the gateway? 
Imagine an instance where I want to have multiple gateway and its own rules associated with same loadbalancer.

Comment: The Istio Ingress Gateway pods have their own labels already, one of them is `istio=ingress-gateway`. I think you can use that one. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You confuse one thing that, in above rule, `match: source.labels["app"] == "my-app"` is not referring to any resource's label, but to pod's label.

From [OutputTemplate Documentation](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/policy-and-telemetry/templates/kubernetes/#OutputTemplate):

> sourceLabels  | Refers to source pod labels.
>   attributebindings can refer to this field using $out.sourcelabels

And you can verify by looking for resources with "app=istio-ingressgateway" label via:

```
kubectl get pods,svc -n istio-system -l "app=istio-ingressgateway" --show-labels
```

You can check this [blog](https://istio.io/blog/2017/adapter-model/) from istio about Mixer Adapter Model, to understand complete mixer model, its handlers,instances and rules.

Hope it helps!